# Should I store multiple instance of the same file?

Tags: php, file, upload

I am working on a web application that a lot of users can upload files. I can store the hash of stored files and check if the file is already on the server and only store some meta data (filename, owner, .… ) and redirect the user to that file when the user need to retrieve that files. I can delete the file when all users soft delete their file.

My question is should I do that on an enterprise application or the additional programming effort weigh out its benefits, cloud drives, ...?

What is the general approach regarding this issue? What about mail servers, social networks and sites similar to SE?

Comment: Don't reinvent [the wheel](https://blogs.oracle.com/bonwick/entry/zfs_dedup).

Comment: Sorry, such question is impossible to answer in a general way. Because that obviously depends on your situation. If you expect many such duplicates, then of course you want to implement that. If not, then probably not. We cannot tell what your situation is.

Answer (score 0):

Only implement the hashing strategy if you can foresee a significant amount of duplicates being uploaded. Otherwise it is not worth adding the unnecessary complexity that you will have to troubleshoot and maintain.